# Checking class of an instance in Java

Tags: java, oop

How do I see if a class overrides another class?

For example: Say `bob` was a `Bot`, a class which overrides the abstract class `Unit`. How can I make the following evaluate to true?

```
bob.getClass() == Unit.class
```

Answer (score 7):

Use the `instanceof` operator:

```
if(bob instanceof Unit) {
    // ...
}
```

---

Note that once you are certain an object is an instance of a class by using `instanceof`, you can safely cast it to that class like so:

```
if(bob instanceof Unit) {
    Unit bobUnit = (Unit) bob;
    bobUnit.unitMethod();
}
```

This may be necessary when calling a function that only the subclass (e.g. `Unit`) has a definition of.

Comment: There are also two other ways of doing it (besides using the operator instanceof): Unit.class.isInstance(bob) or Unit.class.isAssignable(bob.getClass())

Answer (score 1):

If the implementation is

```
Bob implements Unit
```

then

```
bob.getClass().getSuperclass()
```

will return Unit